# Why is generalised velocity written like this

Tags: classical-mechanics, velocity, coordinate-systems

Consider the following extract from [these notes](http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/CM_13/CM-7-2p.pdf):

[image]

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question. For instance, it is not clear to me what you mean by a generalized coordinate having to be "transformed uniquely to cartesian form", or what the "term" you are talking about actually  is.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

This time dependence is intentional on the part of the author, as you can see in the definition of the map from canonical coordinates to cartesian space,
$$
x_j = x_j(q_1,\ldots,q_{n-k},t),
$$
with an explicit time dependence. This formalism therefore enables you to consider situations where at different times the coordinates map to different points. This is because the constraint itself could be changing as a function of time:

[image]

One example where this kind of formalism is useful is the dynamics of a bead on a wire, which is itself on a rotating platform, rollercoaster cart, or other similar non-inertial frame.

Comment: @rpfphysics Generalized coordinates go much further than just a transformation between  Cartesian reference frames - *any* diffeomorphic, time-dependent transformation is allowed. There isn't really such a thing as "force" in generalized coordinates (at least insofar as $\ddot q$ goes), and there is no reason to expect it to remain invariant under the transformations your source considering. That said, your notes are thin on explanations - find a better resource. I would recommend Goldstein, Lanczos, or Gantmacher.

Comment: @rpfphysics No. Spherical coordinates are independent of time, so a point with constant $q$s will have constant $x$s. The mappings in your question *can* depend on time, but that doesn't mean that they *need* to. Then, in addition to, and independently from, this (*possible*) time dependence of the mapping, there is the trajectory over the generalized coordinates: the $q=q(t)$ depend on time, and from there you get a trajectory over cartesian space, $x=x(q(t))$ (or possibly $x=x(q(t),t)$).

Comment: @rpfphysics No. You *can* make a time-dependent coordinate system (which would introduce a nonzero $\partial x/\partial q$) but that is *not* what one means by 'spherical coordinates' unless you point that modification out with big red letters. Moreover, in generalized coordinates, there is no guarantee that "straight line motion" makes sense (because of the constraints) and there's no guarantee that you're in an inertial frame. You need to slow *way* down, and settle in with a solid textbook.

Comment: @rpfphysics That last bit is entirely unclear.

Comment: @rpfphysics Yes, but you should note that there's no requirement that the time dependence in the transformation be linear (think e.g. a mass-on-a-spring that's mounted on an oscillating pendulum), so the only circumstances "only a constant term" can arise are the ones explicitly built for that purpose.

Comment: As an aside, you really need to work on communicating your ideas more clearly; this includes slowing down and actively analysing what you type before you commit to it. In any case, I'll need to leave this conversation now.